# /system cannot be remounted as RW, even when rooted (Sony Xperia E3)

Tags: root-access, file-system, mount, sony-xperia, system

I rooted my Sony Xperia E3 (D2203) a while ago using Kingroot, which worked flawlessly.
Before rooting my device, `/system` could be accessed, which is how root was installed in the first place.

However after rebooting the phone, I now cannot mount `/system` as `rw`, as the kernel mounts it as `Read-Only` and gives me a `Operation not permitted` error whenever I try to remount it as `rw`. Apparently the kernel on Sony devices detects root and mounts `/system` as `Read-Only`.

I cannot flash a new recovery as the bootloader is permanently locked.

What can I do to mount `/system` at startup as `rw`, or mount `/system` when the device is online?

A non-destructive method would be great.

Here is the command I'm using to try and mount `/system`:

`mount -o remount,rw /system`

Yes, the terminal is in root mode.

Comment: `mount -o remount,rw /system`

Comment: I've noticed someone say that `mount -o rw,remount /proc /system` could work. Would this work?

Comment: Why should it? If `/proc` were mounted r/o, many processes would fail (so it's obviously mounted r/w already). So no difference to your previous approach. I rather assume there's some SE_Linux safeguard actively preventing the command – but as I've never played with that, I cannot give any hints on how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) to remount the / directory as RW also remounted /system as RW.

Howto:

1. Enable `Root Functions Everywhere` in TC settings.
2. Proceed to add a new button to the toolbar with Function Type `Internal Command`.
3. Press on the `>>` button, and select the `119 Remount` option.
4. Press `OK/Apply`
5. Navigate to root (`/`) directory.
6. Press newly created Remount button and accept any prompts.

Edit: I've found that when I'm using Kingroot to manage root, mounting works correctly. When I migrated over to SuperSU however, I could not remount `/` or `/system` as RW.
If the above steps don't work for you, Kingroot might be worth a shot.

Another edit: While I do recommend Kingroot as an option to allow access to your `/system` folder, you should exercise caution with Kingroot, as it is known to gather information about your device. I would save Kingroot to be a last resort, should you cannot find any other method of remounting `/system` as `rw` successfully.

Comment: Could you add some details on how to remount drives using Total Commander? Also, a link to the app is encouraged, which has been provided.